# Tag to show Related Content Type and Term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have Content A and Content B
Both share the same taxonomy tags i.e interests i.e football, sport, tennis

When someone clicks on tag 
i,e term "sport"

I want it to show
All Content A with "sport" Terms tags

Not All Content A and B with Sport Terms tags

How can I do this please?

Many Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could create two separate vocabularies each with the same terms in it, then make one vocabulary available to content A and the other vocabulary available to content B.

An alternative is to use views: https://drupal.org/project/views

With Views you can list items of a Content type with certain tags associated with it on a page.

E.g. I have two content types News & events both are categorized by term group. I only want display all News items so I use Views to only show content type News.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I use [Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module

It allows you to create URL aliases for all content, users, taxonomy terms etc.

When you enable it look for URL aliases in Administer. Then there is a tab called Automated alias settings. In there you can select which content types and taxonomy terms have which alias.

Comment: This is *not* a forum. Please edit your post to expand your answer instead of writing a second answer.